# I can't add web reference from wsdl

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I can't add the web reference from a wsdl file. I am getting an error.
But it is working normally with SoapUI.

> "RPC Message getFaturaResponse in operation getKurumSTFatura has an invalid body name getFaturaResponse. It must be getKurumSTFaturaResponse"

```
    abonePortTypeClient client = new abonePortTypeClient();

    if (client.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
    {

        string outresult = string.Empty;
        var param35 = new AboneClient.SahaIsemri();
        param35.tesisatno = 1;
        param35.emirturu = 7;
        param35.altemirturu = 5;
        param35.elemankodu = 3208;


        string resultstring = null;
        var SahaIsemri = new AboneClient.SahaIsemri();

        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "XXX";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "XXX";

        var aaa = client.putSahaIsemri(param35, out resultstring, out SahaIsemri);


    }
```

Comment: Your connection to the webservice is ok. Did you develope the webservice or where is it from?

Comment: Yes, I connected. But I am getting error while executing a method.

Comment: Can you post the complete stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers that the references generated by wsdl does not match.

```
getFaturaResponse in operation getKurumSTFatura has an invalid body name getFaturaResponse. It must be getKurumSTFaturaResponse
```

You need to change the Operation in the service or you need to manually change in the reference.cs file.

Search for the particular method and rename the response as above!

Answer (score 0):

@Sajeetharan's answer is fine, but I had some problems finding what I had to rename. Just in case it can help someone, you have to look for the WrapperName in the MessageContractAttribute. In the example above, it would be something like:

```
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="getKurumSTFatura", WrapperNamespace="xxxx", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class getFaturaResponse {
```